# operator<<() for template class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to overload `operator <<()` for my own class that is also a template.  My classes are as follows:

```
template<
    typename RefCountType,
    typename TraitsType = std::char_traits<char>,
    typename Allocator = std::allocator<typename TraitsType::char_type>
>
class rep {
    // ...
};

template<typename RepType>
class t_zstring {
    // ...
};
```

The code for `operator<<()` is:

```
template<
  typename CharType,
  typename TraitsType,
  typename Allocator,
  typename RefCountType,
  template<class,class,class> class RepType
>
inline std::basic_ostream<CharType,TraitsType>&
operator<<( std::basic_ostream<CharType,TraitsType> &os,
            t_zstring< RepType<RefCountType,TraitsType,Allocator> > const &s ) {
  return os << s.c_str();
}
```

The template code compiles just fine; however, when I attempt to use it like (with the code for the `my_ref_count` class elided):

```
typedef rep<my_ref_count> my_rep;
typedef t_zstring<my_rep> zstring;
zstring z;
cout << z; // ztest.cpp, line 201
```

I get (using g++ 4.2.1):

```
ztest.cpp:201: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << z1’
```

How can I declare my `operator<<()` correctly so the compiler will find the correct match?

Comment: Shouldn't `operator<<()` take only one parameter?

Comment: @klez - no, since `operator<<` is a free function here, it needs two parameters.

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko, perfect, now I'm even more sure I don't know C++ well :D

Comment: Seems to work for me... http://ideone.com/zGdSm

Comment: Besides a couple of silly errors `t_ztring` instead of `t_zstring`, it compiles (assuming that `t_zstring` has a `c_str` defined.

Comment: @dribeas: The "silly errors" were typos in transcription to stackoverflow.  As I said, the only error I got was the one I cited above.

Comment: @jpalecek: I suppose g++ 4.2.1 is broken.  Unfortunately, it's the latest available from Apple for Mac OS X.

Comment: You can give a try with clang (XCode 4.6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define the << operator for class t_zstring, I think it is easier to write:

```
template<typename OS, typename RepType>
OS& operator<<(OS &os, t_zstring<RepType> const &s ) 
{ 
  return os << s.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Except that doesn't restrict the type of OS to be a std::basic_ostream.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 
As you suggested that g++ 4.2.1 may be broken, I thought an easier declaration may solve it.
After all, restricting OS to std::basic_ostream is not always necessary.